# How to fix ( could not find file) exception

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I am using `vb.net` with Microsoft Access 2013. Before creating a setup of my project it was working correctly but after setup and saving it to a new folder on the desktop, the system can't even login and is returning following error.

```
Could not find file 
C:\users\Serudzai \appdata\local\apps\2.0\data\......\pharmacy. Accdb
```

Comment: If you're told that that file can't be found then that file can't be found.  You need to make sure that the file is in the right place and that you're looking for it in the right place.  Did you actually include that file in your deployment package?  The most obvious explanation would be that you didn't.

Comment: you really have a space after "Serudzai"? and a space before "Accdb"?

Comment: if you typed that error manually, you're making it hard for us to help you

Comment: also make sure you take a look at Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData) & "\2.0\data......\pharmacy.Accdb"
```

you can also use path.combine to combine the 2 strings